How to partially modify SystemUIOverlayStyle in Flutter
I'm attempting to modify the SystemUIOverlayStyle in my Flutter application, but I'm encountering a warning indicating that 'latestStyle' is only accessible for testing purposes. What alternative approach can I use to obtain the current system UI overlay, allowing me to update specific properties while adhering to best practices?
Below is the snippet of my code for reference:
SystemUiOverlayStyle? existingOverlayStyle = SystemChrome.latestStyle; // I am getting the warning here
var newOverlayStyle = existingOverlayStyle?.copyWith(
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, //I want to update only the statusBarColor while leaving the rest of the other properties untouched
);
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(newOverlayStyle!);

Thank you for any insights or suggestions!"
